# HandsOnTable: How to load an array from a PHP server script?

Tags: php, jquery, handsontable

I'm having issues loading an array using a PHP script through an Ajax layer then pushing the resulting array into the HandsOnTable component plugin. I "think" my problem is that regardless of what I attempt, the resulting array is turned into an Object (having tested it with a typeof()) check.

Here's my PHP:

```
$listArray[] = array('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email','Status');
```

Here's my returning JSON:

```
{"returnText":"OK","returnCode":"200","listArray":[["First Name","Last Name","Email","Status"]]}
```

Here's my Javascript post-jQuery.parseJSON():

```
bulkListData = returnText['listArray'];

$("#table").handsontable({
      data: bulkListData,
      [...other values below...]
}
```

The returning array is an object. I've looked up several posts on how to convert this to an array on the client side, but all methods result in an Object var. As I understand it HandsOnTable requires an array during the data: load construction.

Looking for anyone with experience loading data from a PHP server script and then assigning it into the HandsOnTable component.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. It wasn't the return type. I had my dataSchema mismatched to the resulting array.

Modified my PHP:

```
$listArray[] = array('name'=>array('first'=>$candidate['name_first'],'last'=>$candidate['name_last']),'email'=>$candidate['email'],'status'=>"");
```

Modified my Javascript HandsOnTable declaration:

```
dataSchema: {name: {first: null, last: null}, email: null,status: null},
      colHeaders: ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email','Status'],
      columns: [
        {data: 'name.first'},
        {data: 'name.last'},
        {data: 'email'},
        {data: 'status'}
      ],
```